# Add a <f:actionListener type="ListenerClass"> programmatically

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, sap-erp

In my JSF-Page I have an input-field with a browse button (it's part of `<%@ taglib prefix="sap" uri="http://java.sap.com/jsf/html/extended"%>`)

```
<sap:commandInputText>
   <f:attribute name="upperCase" value="false" />
   <f:actionListener type="PackageAndNameOfAClass"/>
</sap:commandInputText>
```

Now I want to create such a UI-Component programmatically.

The `<f:attribute>` is not a problem. But I have no idea how to handle the `<f:actionListener type="...">`.

`UICommandInputText inputField.setActionListener` wants a Method-Expression

`UICommandInputText inputField.addActionListener` wants a Action-Listener

But I have only the Name of the Class and will put it in this "type-Attribute".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I use this methods in a Generic managedBean that all my MB extends. (or you could make it static as well in a **Util** class)

```
public MethodExpression createAction(String actionExpression, Class<?> returnType) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), actionExpression, returnType, new Class[0]);
}

public MethodExpressionActionListener createActionListener(String actionListenerExpression) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return new MethodExpressionActionListener(context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory()
        .createMethodExpression(context.getELContext(), actionListenerExpression, null, new Class[] {ActionEvent.class}));
}
```

You call it this way:

```
htmlCommandButton.addActionListener(this.createActionListener("#{questionarioMB.enviarFormulario}"));
```

---

*A web site with useful JSF methods:*

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/5-useful-methods-jsf-developers-should.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Unfortunately it not really solve my problem.

But I solved it =)

The Class I wnat to write in this "type-parameter", implements the action-listener so I can directly use inputField.addActionListener(actionListener); ... where actionListener is a instance of the class that implements the javax.faces.event.ActionListener